# Wordpress' post_time won't work with Custom PHP time difference calculator

Tags: php, wordpress, timestamp

I'm using this script (http://snipplr.com/view/4912/relative-time/) to create relative times using PHP and timestamps stored in my database. I'm using the standard format for storing datetime (eg 2010-05-07 20:26:17) and it works fine with any timestamps I create.

But for some reason when I try to use a timestamp stored in wordpress's wp_posts table, the function fails and returns "January 1, 1970". I can't see any difference in the format of wordpress' timestamps and my own. And I can use wordpress' data fine using the `date()` function to present a formatted date, just not a relative time using my own function.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the dates fine with `date()` then you probably have them in UNIX timestamp format already. Try removing the `strtotime()` calls in `getRelativeTime()` (on line 7 and 22).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that script - WordPress has a human time difference function you can use

To print an entry's time ("2 days ago"):

```
<?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' ago'; ?>
```

For comments:

```
 <?php echo human_time_diff(get_comment_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' ago'; ?>
```